# How to express Polynomial in a certain format with Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

**Equations**

```
A = {{-0.03333, 0, 0}, {0.0667, -0.6799, 0.6667}, {0,     0.3399, -0.3467}};
B = {0.0333, 0, 0};
CC = {1, 1, 1};
myInverse = Inverse[s*IdentityMatrix[3] - A];
P = CC*myInverse*B;
P = P[[1,1]];
```

**Goal**

> Express the polynomial $P$ in the format $\frac{1}{1+\text{something}}$.

**Trials**

> **1. Trial:** tried to play with denominator and numerator, FAIL, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnFCW.png).
>
> **2. Trial:** tried Solve command but errs, the code [here](http://pastie.org/5483974) fires the error with a transfer function $G(s)$ and the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGteK.png). I try to express the line 146 i.e. the equation $G(s)$ in the form $\frac{1}{1+C}$. How can I simplify this? Why do I get the error? How can I get the equation for the $G(s)$ in the requested form? Err report "Solve::ivar: ... is not a valid variable".
>
> **3. Trial:** fixing the preserved-variable problem revealed by Artes's answer, I get very peculiar answer -- I get empty set!? Why? I should get some non-empty equation. Notice the line 336 in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAREM.png).

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi thank you for the notice, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Solve[ mySeries == 1/(1 + A), A]` because `A` had been defined in your code. Moreover you can't use capital `C` because

> ```
> it is the default form for the i-th parameter or constant generated in representing
> the results of various symbolic computations.
> ```

`mySeries` has been defined with `mySeries = Series[ P[[1, 1]], {s, 0, 1}];` thus it has the value in terms of `SeriesData` :

```
Head @ mySeries
```

> ```
> SeriesData
> ```

therefore you should use `Normal`. Because of inexact coefficients  `Solve` produces this message :

> ```
> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients.
> The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing
> the result. >>
> ```

If you want to suppress the message use `Quiet`. 
 Then you'll get the result :

```
Solve[ Normal[mySeries] == 1/(1 + x), x] // Quiet
```

> ```
> {{x -> (0.333333 (-3.19716*10^7 - 1.06476*10^12 s))/(-1.18295*10^10 + 3.5492*10^11 s)}}
> ```

A bit more involved algebraic expression was `P` and you wanted to find `P[[1,1]]` in the form `1/(1 + x)`. You can use the `MaxExtraConditions` option in `Solve` to get all conditions for a general solution.

```
Solve[ 1/(1 + x) == P[[1, 1]], x, MaxExtraConditions -> All] // Quiet
```

or if you know that conditions are satisfied you may simply write

```
1/(1 + x) /. Solve[ 1/(1 + x) == P[[1, 1]], x] // Quiet
```

to get the result in the expected form.

Comment: @hhh You wanted `mySeries == 1/(1+x)` so write simply `1/(1 + x) /. Solve[ Normal[mySeries] == 1/(1 + x), x] // Quiet`

Comment: @hhh You are welcome. I recommend to edit your question once more and put your equations in a good order. Next you needn`t  use `P = P[[1]][[1]]` because you set another value to `P` which was originally a matrix , moreover you can simply use `P[[1,1]]` instead of `P[[1]][[1]]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only after "something" you could simply employ

```
something = Denominator[P]/Numerator[P] - 1 // Together
```

Note that system commands generally start with a capital letter.  You can also apply 
this to `Normal[ mySeries]` (instead of `P`) if you wish/require. For target expressions more general than `1/(1+something)` Artes answer can always be generalized.